# Is there a package to send a piece of text to shell and get the result back?

Tags: shell, shell-command

I want to know if there is a package to send a piece of text to shell commands like sed, awk or other text processing utilities and then get the result back to emacs? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly, but there's no need to install a package for this; it's built in.

The command `shell-command-on-region` (bound to `M-|` by default) prompts for and then executes a shell command, sending it whatever you have selected on stdin, then displays the output in a temporary buffer. With a prefix arg (so `C-u M-|`) it replaces the contents of the region with the output of the command.

There are other details in the documentation, so you might want to read it. Type `C-h f shell-command-on-region RET` to open a help buffer for the command. This and other commands are also documented in the Emacs manual. `C-h i` will open the info viewer with a list of all the available manuals. Select emacs, then navigate to section 40, Running Shell Commands from Emacs. You can jump right to it by typing `M-: (info "(emacs)Shell")`, but that's a bit of a mouth-full.